# Installed ruby-1.9 (rvm) and rails 3, mongrel or thin uses system ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-1.9, rvm

I am using rvm

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.5.0 [ i386-java ]
   jruby-1.5.1 [ i386-java ]
   ruby-1.8.7-p299 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
```

with:

```
rails -v
Rails 3.0.0.rc
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

However, when starting rails (with either webrick or thin), the ruby interpretor used is ruby 1.8.7:

```
rails s
/home/vlad/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/rubyeventmachine.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
```

Why is rails server using system ruby instead of local ruby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that I was using the same gemset that I have created with ruby-1.8.7.

Changing to:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2@rails3ruby19 --create
gem install bundler --pre
bundle install
rails s
```

and now the interpreter used is ruby 1.9.2